# Python : Accessing elements of inner most list in nested lists

Tags: python

If i have nested list as below, how do i first access `['*', '5', '8']`(innermost list) so that i can perform multiplication and then move on to next innermost list i.e `['*',[result_from_previous_step],'9']` and so on till outer most list is found

```
['*', ['*', ['*', '5', '8'], '9'], '10']
```

This seems some what like evaluating a tree to me but in bottom up fashion

Comment: What was your attempt to achieve that?

Comment: This is exactly like evaluating a tree -- You just have to determine at each step if the operands are trees and recursively evaluate them.  If they aren't trees (they're leaves), then you skip evaluating that branch and just evaluate the expression.

Comment: @ettanany I was not sure how to go about this but like i said in my question was thinking of achieving this by evaluating tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to write a recursive function that calls itself to evaluate the inner expressions.

```
# helper function to parse strings where necessary
def intorfloat(number):
    if not isinstance(number, str):   # already parsed
       return number
    try:
        return int(number)
    except ValueError:
        return float(number)

# evaluates a simple expression (no subexpressions)
def evaluate2(operation, operand1, operand2):
    operand1, operand2 = intorfloat(operand1), intorfloat(operand2)
    if operation == "*":
        return operand1 * operand2
    elif operation == "+":
        return operand1 + operand2
    elif operation == "/":
        # keep the result an int if possible
        result1 = operand1 // operand2
        result2 = float(operand1) / operand2
        return result1 if result1 == result2 else result2
    elif operation == "-":
        return operand1 - operand2

# recursively evaluate an expression with subexpressions
def evaluate(expression):
    operation, operand1, operand2 = expression
    if isinstance(operand1, list):
        operand1 = evaluate(operand1)
    if isinstance(operand1, list):
        operand2 = evaluate(operand2)
    return evaluate2(operation, operand1, operand2)
```

An iterative solution is also possible; the advantage is that you can evaluate expressions of any depth. In this version, we keep descending into sublists until we find a leaf: an expression that doesn't have any subexpressions. Then we evaluate the leaf and replace it with its result, and start over from the beginning. Eventually the top-level expression has no subexpressions.

This algorithm actually modifies the expression, repeatedly simplifying it until it's trivial to evaluate it. (The recursive solution does not modify the expression.)

If the expression is deep, we may do a lot of unnecessary traversal to repeatedly find leaf nodes. We could create a stack to allow us to backtrack instead of having to start at the top each time, but we might as well just use the recursive solution at that point.

```
# uses intorfloat() and evaluate2() functions previously shown

def evaluate(expression):
    while isinstance(expression[1], list) or isinstance(expression[2], list):
        current = expression
        container = None
        while True:         # find a leaf node
            operation, operand1, operand2 = current
            if isinstance(operand1, list):
               container, slot = current, 1
               current = operand1
            elif isinstance(operand2, list):
                container, slot = current, 2
                current = operand2
            else:
                break
        if container:
            container[slot] = evaluate2(*current)
    return evaluate2(*expression)

print evaluate(['*', ['*', ['*', '5', '8'], '9'], '10'])   # 3600
```

Comment: Also, there is a `operator` module to perform mathematical operations

Comment: Yes, you could write that code using a dictionary and `operator` functions; I just didn't want to bamboozle him too much.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough solution of your problem

```
l = ['*', ['*', ['*', '5', '8'], '9'], '10']

def islist(l):
    try:
        l.append
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False

def reduce(l):
    if islist(l):
        return recurse(l)
    else:
        return l

def recurse(l):
    if not islist(l):
        return l

    first = reduce(l[0])
    second = reduce(l[1])
    third = reduce(l[2])

    return "({} {} {})".format(second, first, third)

print recurse(l)
```

Which uses recursion. Python is not the best language to implement recursive algorithms, pure functional languages like Erlang are more powerful on such topics.

The major problems are the maximum number of recursive calls and the memory occupation, but for such a small list this works.

One problem you can have is how to tell apart lists and other things, which is not so simple. You can use isinstance() or try/except like I do. The collections module is not that helpful in this case because both lists and strings are sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You may create your custome recursive function using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to achieve this as:

```
def perform_operation(my_list):
    temp_list = []
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            item = perform_operation(item)
        temp_list.append(item)
    return eval('{} {} {}'.format(temp_list[1], temp_list[0], temp_list[2]))
```

Sample run:

```
>>> my_list = ['*', ['*', ['*', '5', '8'], '9'], '10']
>>> perform_operation(my_list)
3600
```

*Note:* Using eval is not safe as it executes the content of string no matter what it has. So, be sure regarding what you pass to it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "more Pythonic" and more easily extendable version of what kindall proposed above. It also does not assume that the numbers are integer.

```
import operator
def evaluate(expression):
    if isinstance(expression, str):
        return float(expression)

    op, operand1, operand2 = expression
    ops = {"*" : operator.mul, 
           "+" : operator.add, 
           "/" : operator.truediv, 
           "-" : operator.sub}
    return ops[op](evaluate(operand1), evaluate(operand2))    

evaluate(['*', ['*', ['*', '5', '8'], '9'], '10'])
```