# How to find innermost level of a list in python

Tags: python, list, nested

So, say you had a list such as `[0,[0,[0,1]]]` or `[[[0],1],1]`, how would I write a piece of code to find the innermost entries, so in the first example it should return `[0,1]`, while in the second example it should return `[0]`. The only way I know how to do it is something like this: `[k for k in [i for i in...`, and I tried this, but I couldn't find a way to generalise it to arbitrarily nested arrays. Does anyone know how to do this using python? Thanks.

Comment: Why should it return `[]` in the second example and not `[0]`?

Comment: recursion is your friend here

Comment: > Why should it return [] in the second example and not [0]
Sorry, typo

Comment: What is the innermost level for `[ [0], [[1]] ]`? Is it `[0]` or `[1]` or both?

Comment: > It should return `[1]` since it is nested deeper within brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Accessing elements of inner most list in nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775271/python-accessing-elements-of-inner-most-list-in-nested-lists)

Comment: gold_cy and Yawar Khan have already answered it, but thanks to directing me to this link. I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively easy problem using recursion. Iterate over your data, if the item is a `list` call the function within itself using that level, otherwise `continue`. Once the loop is complete just return that current level which is our break out condition which will only be reached when that level has no inner lists.

```
def innermost(data):
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            return innermost(item)
        else:
            continue
    return data


innermost([0,[0,[0,1]]])
> [0, 1]

innermost([[[0],1],1])
> [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution which finds the deepest level and the contents of the deepest level in a python list of unknown number of hierarchies.

```
a = [0,[0,[0,1]], 1, [1,2,[5,6,9,[6,6,6,6]]]

depths = []
maxLevel = 0
deepestList = []

def findDeepest(arr, level):
    global depths
    global maxLevel
    global deepestList
    for item in arr:
        if type(item) == list:
            level = level + 1
            depths.append(level)
            if level > maxLevel:
                maxLevel = level
                deepestList = item
            findDeepest(item, level)
    return max(depths), deepestList
    
results = findDeepest(a, 0)

print("Deepest level is: ", results[0])
print("Deepest list is: ",results[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting a code, and helping me out.